# Should i trim my avocado plant through the winter?

Tags: trees, avocado

I have several baby avocado plants that grew this summer. 2 of them i managed to get a first trim while it was still hot out, but at least 2 did not get a trimming. They are currently about 8-12 inches tall. Should i go ahead and cut them, even though its almost autumn? Or should i leave them till its nearer to spring?
I will be bringing them inside, as it does get very cold here in the winter (northeast states in the US).

Comment: Pictures would be nice.  And Northeast states in what country?

Comment: No I dont think that will be necessary; let them be.

Comment: @kevinsky Whoops, in the USA. My apologies. Ill try to remember to take some pictures when its light out

Comment: I tried adding photos, but the post wont let me.